# How to create different user permission to specific parts in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, permissions

My webpage has html and css. a sign in mechanism that has input username/email/password/status(teacher or student), a SQLi database and also Apache and MYSQL started in XAMP control panel. a toogle function that can be opened and closed when user not signed in.

First Picture:I have created the webpage when there is no sign in.

Second Picture:
HOW TO DO THIS PART: which is when i sign in as "teacher" with username and password. Only the teacher "hide/show" is available (+) while the student "hide/show" is still locked.

Third Picture:
HOW TO DO THIS PART: And when i clicked on teacher "hide/show"(+), the solution is shown (-)

Likewise, if i will to sign in as "student" with username and password.  Only the student "hide/show" is available (+) while the teacher "hide/show" is still locked. And when i clicked on student "hide/show"(+), the solution is shown (-)

Is it possible to code it out yourself, or what tools do i need to download .

[image]

Comment: Not possible on the client only. You can ajax the content and have different AUTH set up from the different URLs you Ajax from

Comment: in order for us to help you, you should state what you already tried. Because your problem is pretty complex. To actually have some "sign in" mechanics, you'll need a backend server to perform the authentication. And to conditionally show content depending on the login status, you'll either need a server based html generation or a client based java script program/framework.

Comment: Sorry deleting.

Comment: @mplungjan Well that was part of the question, I should not have deleted. "Third Picture: HOW TO DO THIS PART: And when i clicked on teacher "hide/show"(+), the solution is shown (-)". It is toggle function.

Comment: `My webpage completed with html and css only` so I read this as the click on the plus will test the AUTH before expanding an existing accordion - where the accordion feature already working

Comment: For :  EasterBunnyBugSmasher and @mplungjan: i managed to have a sign in

Comment: Thank you for such fast answers
 For :  EasterBunnyBugSmasher and @mplungjan: i managed to have a sign in mechanism that has for username email password and status(teacher or student) and a SQL database to store what is typed in. So based on what both of you said should i focus on ajax next to help me create this function ("conditionally show content depending on the login status") .

Comment: Thank you for such fast answers 
For – Gosi : i managed to toggle too. But its already working without the sign in.  I need the two different toogle (teachers and students) to conditionally show content depending on the login status. Do I need to change the code inside the html or css in order for the function to work?

Comment: Is it possible for you to recommend a few tutorials, links or website that teaches this (conditionally show content depending on the login status,). I have some difficulty researching  this particular function as most teaches people how to password protect the website or the page only

Answer (score 0):

You have to use php, or any backend programming language. You said, that your page made by html and css. Start to use backend and database.

If you doing this, this will be very easy. Like if you create user table, you can give an attribute, like teacher. This is boolean, or int, what you want.

In backend, create an if fuction.
Like

```
if(teacher==true){
   //show page
}
else{
   // dont show
}
```

It is just a tipp. It is an easy way, but harder way is exist.

I hope i helped.

Comment: Thank you for such prompt reply 
To Norbert Molnar, 
Based on your reply, it seems that it can be done using php.  Is it possible for you to recommend a few tutorials, links or website that teaches this. I have some difficulty researching  this particular function as most teaches people how to password protect the website or the page only and not conditionally show content depending on the login status
.

Comment: Ofcorse :) 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjwc8ScTHnY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LC9GaXkdxF8

Comment: interestingly. i used this youtube video to create my login system. but this video did not teach how to "conditionally show content depending on the login status . " do u mind telling me how to implement your method or a link that teaches what you typed "if(teacher==true){
   //show page
}
else{
   // dont show
}"   because this youtube video is what i perceived as "password protect the website or the page only" which i had already done it

Comment: It will be easy. 

Create a database, example mysql. In your html code.

// html code
<?php if($teacher==true) : ?>
//html show content
<?php elseif($teacher==false) : ?>
//html other content
<?php endif; ?>